# Hyperlinks in SharePoint 2010 built with query string ID={@ID} results in ID=

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

We just upgraded from MOSS 2007 to SPS 2010. There were several ASPX pages built with SharePoint designer that had data from lists appear in tabular format.

What used to work:
If a Title was hyperlinked http://site.com/something.aspx?ID={@ID} in SharePoint Designer, the resulting hyperlink on the webpage for row with ID 5 was site.com/something.aspx?ID=5.

What doesn't work:
The hyperlink that showed site.com/something.aspx?ID=5 on the webpage now shows site.com/something.aspx?ID=. Query string ID has no value. I am clueless as to what happened there and how to resolve this.

What we tried and didn't work:
We removed and recreated the hyperlink using Designer 2010, this time choosing fx formula icon and choosing the ID but the result was the same - ID query string had no value for any row that appeared on the webpage.

Has anyone seen such a behavior? If so, how would you go about solving it?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the same issue with one of my DVWPs.. I used a Query String 'ID' to filter a DVWP. After migrating to 2010 the filter stopped working. Whever the ID was more that 5 higher than the first ID in the list, I got the error message that no element was found....
After changing the name of the Query String it started working again right away..

Well, can have'm all...

Answer (score 1):

Could you try changing the name of the QueryString from ID to something else, like ProductId?

The link would be something like: http://site.com/something.aspx?ProductId=

I`ve had strange behaviours when using "ID" as the QueryString term.

Answer (score 1):

Querystring parameters you should not use in your SharePoint application

- FeatureId
- ListTemplate
- List
- ID
- VersionNo
- ContentTypeId
- RootFolder
- View
- FolderCTID
- Mode
- Type

[Source](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2009/01/30/querystring-parameters-you-should-not-use-in-your-sharepoint-application.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you're describing must be a DVWP. They should work exactly the same in 2010 as in 2007. I haven't seen a well-built one not upgrade.

Is the hyperlink you show inside a dvt_1.rowview template or some other template in the DVWP's XSL?